# How to change the language of drop-down menu of the UI of a Watson Assistant Chatbot

Tags: drop-down-menu, ibm-cloud, chatbot, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

When I created the assistant, I chose the Spanish Language. However, the label of the drop-down menu is still in English: "Select an option"

[image]

Is there a way to change that label? (From "Select an option" to another language or whatever label I might want to use)

Comment: What is your browser setting for language?

Comment: @data_henrik It was English. I changed it to Spanish on both Chrome and Firefox, but still the text says: "Select an option" in English. Thanks a lot for commenting!

Answer (score 2):

You can use `instance.updateLanguagePack()`

```
const customLanguagePack = {
  "options_select": "Select"
};
instance.updateLanguagePack(customLanguagePack);
```

- https://web-chat.global.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com/docs.html?to=api-instance-methods#updatelanguagepack
- https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/assistant-web-chat/blob/main/languages/en.json